# How to choose devices camera (from multiple back cameras, i want the main) for barcodescanning with QuaggaJS?

Tags: android, quaggajs

I have implemented the QuaggaJS library to scan barcodes from a mobile device in my laravel application but e.g. for my mobile phone which has multiple backcameras the chosen camera has a weird "fish eye" effect so i guess it is not the main/standard camera. The only setting i know about is to set the facingMode either 'environment' or 'user' as shown in my codesnippet below.

```
constraints: {
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
            facingMode: 'environment', }
```

I would like to know if there is an option to specify the camera used?

Thanks in advance.